# Node.js cheerio weird characters (cyrillic letters)

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

I get weird characters when i am trying to parse a page.

Here is my code:

```
var getPageContent = function getPageContent(url, callback) {
    https.get(url, function (res) {
        var data = "";
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        res.on("end", function () {
            callback(data));
        });
    }).on("error", function () {
        callback(null);
    });
};

getPageContent(url, function (response) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(response, { decodeEntities: false });
    $("div.details-info").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
});
```

My result is:

```
<span>Ст��атегии</span>
<span>Стратег��и</span>
<span>Стра��егии</span>
<span>Стратегии</span>
<span>Стратегии</span>
...
```

The strangest thing is that from same url, sometimes i get this strange characters, sometimes i don't. And also when i am running this from my computer it's working fine. I get this characters on server only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to manually convert the charset of `response` to UTF-8. You can do this using the `iconv` or `iconv-lite` modules. `cheerio` itself does not automatically handle charset conversions.